# How to change font in $$ which is in math form in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

When I tried to polt a figure with matplotlib, I wrote the x axis label with both text and "math text". Because I have to write a chemical formula in the label, it was written as '$CO_2$ concentration'. The question is that I hope the font should be times new roman, but I cannot change the font in the dollar sign somehow. Is there anyone who can help me fix it? Thank you very much!

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

xf1 = pd.read_excel('1812_GPT.xlsx',sheetname= 'PVD_CO2CH4_600',usecols=[1])
deltapx1 = pd.read_excel('1812_GPT.xlsx',sheetname= 'PVD_CO2CH4_600',usecols=[3])
Px1 = pd.read_excel('1812_GPT.xlsx',sheetname= 'PVD_CO2CH4_600',usecols=[5])

ax1 = plt.subplot(111) 

l1, = ax1.plot(xf1,Px1,'s',markerfacecolor='black')

font1 = {'family' : 'Times New Roman',
'weight' : 'normal',
'size'   : 14,
 }

ax1.set_xlabel(r'$CO_2$ pressure', font1)
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$CO_2$ concentration', font1)

plt.show()
```

This is the picture link, you may see the pic and find that "CO2" is not in Times new roman.
https://flic.kr/p/2dmh8pj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's easily possible to change any mathtext to an arbitrary font. However, in case of `"CO_2"` that consists only of **regular symbols**, you may use `\mathdefault{}` to make the mathtext use the symbols from the regular font.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"
plt.rcParams["font.serif"] = ["Times New Roman"] + plt.rcParams["font.serif"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathdefault{CO_2}$ pressure')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\mathdefault{CO_2}$ concentration')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Something like `r"$\mathdefault{\sum_\alpha^\beta\frac{i}{9}}$` would still be rendered in the usual default math fontset (except the  `"i"` and the `9`, which are of course present in Times New Roman).

[image]

For the **general case**, you may also change the complete math fontset to any of the available, `cm`, `stix`, `stixsans`, `dejavuserif`, `dejavusans`. The closest to "Times New Roman" would be `stix`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rc = {"font.family" : "serif", 
      "mathtext.fontset" : "stix"}
plt.rcParams.update(rc)
plt.rcParams["font.serif"] = ["Times New Roman"] + plt.rcParams["font.serif"]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlabel(r'$CO_2$ pressure')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$CO_2$ concentration')

plt.show()
```

[image]

A general recommendation for reading would be the [MathText tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html).

Answer (score 1):

I find it better to define the whole font family at once, rather than independently (assuming you want the same font). Give this a try

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True )
plt.rc('font', family='Times New Roman', weight='normal', size=14)
plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'Times New Roman'
ax1.set_xlabel('$CO_2$ pressure')
ax1.set_ylabel('$CO_2$ concentration')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, it didn't work. The font of "CO2" didn't change. Btw, do I need to import something in the beginning?

Comment: Just import what you are already importing. Have a try again using `plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'Times New Roman'` as I have edited in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
plt.rcParams['mathtext.rm'] = 'Times New Roman'
plt.rcParams['font.family'] ='Times New Roman'
```

In this case, the math text font will be custom based on the [math text documentation on custom fonts](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html#custom-fonts). This comes with it's own limitations, but in your basic case, will work as intended.

The code for your x-axis would then be the following: `ax1.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{CO_2}$ pressure')` without having to specify within the label.

Note: I do not specify a fallback font in this scenario, which may be necessary in more complex character cases. It is explained in the documentation linked above.