# plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix' is not working

Tags: python

I'm not sure what the reason causing this, but when I apply this command line `plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'` in labelling x-axis, it will not change the math symbol to font like Times New Roman.
Did anyone how can I fix this?

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'        
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
plt.xlabel("COM Distance Between Polymer and Calcite Surface ($\AA$)",fontname="Times New Roman",fontsize=12)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change font globably with `plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"`

so

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "serif"
plt.rcParams["font.serif"] = ["Times New Roman"] + plt.rcParams["font.serif"]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator()) 
plt.xlabel("COM Distance Between Polymer and Calcite Surface ($\mathdefault{\AA}$)",fontname="Times New Roman",fontsize=12)
```

Comment: I try this before but but I'm not sure why it only apply to Legend. For math symbol and x y label the font will not change...

Comment: I see, well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679650/how-to-change-font-in-which-is-in-math-form-in-python showed you can use `\mathdefault{}` but thats only for the special math symbols, i've updated my answer to show it.